# how can I use scrolling in the horizontal direction?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Friends, how can I use scrolling in the horizontal direction?

https://codesandbox.io/s/klcs8?file=/src/Example.jsx

Comment: There are many places where `width` is static and `height` is dynamic, and there are properties like `drag="y"`. Have you tried changing any of these so that it would go in the x direction? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below modified sandbox url for horizontal scrolling:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/the-framer-book-example-animations-16-scroll-refresh-forked-mfhdvr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import { motion, useMotionValue, useTransform } from "framer-motion";

const items = [0, 1, 2,3,4,5];
const width = 80;
const padding = 10;
const size = 150;

export function Example() {
    const scrollX = useMotionValue(0);
    const scale = useTransform(scrollX, [0, 100], [0, 1]);
    const opacity = useTransform(scrollX, [0, 100], [0, 1]);

    return (
        <>
            <motion.div
                style={{
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    borderRadius: 20,
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: "35%",
                    marginTop: 15,
                    left: "40%",
                    marginLeft: -50,
                    scale: scale,
                    opacity: opacity
                }}
            />
            <motion.div
                style={{
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    borderRadius: 30,
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    position: "relative",
                    transform: "translateZ(0)",
                    cursor: "grab"
                }}
                whileTap={{ cursor: "grabbing" }}
            >
                <motion.div
                    style={{
                        height: 150,
                        width: getWidth(items),
                        x: scrollX
                    }}
                    drag="x"
                    dragConstraints={{
                        left: -getWidth(items) + size,
                        right: 0
                    }}
                >
                    {items.map((index) => {
                        return (
                            <motion.div
                                style={{
                                    width: width,
                                    height: 150,
                                    borderRadius: 20,
                                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                                    float:"left",
                                    marginRight:
                                        index !== items.length - 1 ? 10 : 0
                                }}
                                key={index}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                    
                </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
        </>
    );
}

function getWidth(items) {
    const totalWidth = items.length * width;
    const totalPadding = (items.length - 1) * padding;
    const totalScroll = totalWidth + totalPadding;
    return totalScroll;
}
```